# , how to open and close screen with effect like Facebook?

Tags: iphone, xcode, facebook, ios4, three20

I'm using three20 for my dashboard.
(ttlauncher)

Now when I select a icon to open a screen
How do I make the screen open like Facebook? (small to big)

And close to  return to the dashboard like Facebook? (big to small) 
Do I need to modify the ui screens to use three20 aswell? Or the effect is standard iOS effects?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These are custom animations developed by the team who worked on the App.

If you download the Facebook iOS SDK you should be able to have a glimpse at how it's done by looking through the source code and using it as a reference.

https://github.com/facebook/facebook-ios-sdk

Of particular interest to you is the FBDialog class (which is a UIView subclass).